# rare error when running my function in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have two function. One to train a classifier and one to predict test data. If I run the predict function step by step it works fine, however If I call the predict function I get  an error. I can't know what is happening due to the code of the function has no errors compiled manually. I've upload the two functions and the data on Github.[you can access here](https://github.com/runningR/code_functions)

```
modelFit=mdp(Class = dades[,1],data=dades[,-1],lambda = 1,info.pred = T)
predict.mdp(modelFit, dades[1:5,-1])
Error in D[row, i] : subscript out of bounds
```

Thank you for anything you can do to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I could see was  that in  `D[row, i]` , variable `row` was overshooting the number of rows in D. 
`row` itself is derived from vec.new : `for(row in vec.new)`

This piece is the culprit :

```
start=dim(D)[1]
vec.new=(start+1):(start+dim(newdata)[1])
```

`vec.new` starts from `nrow(D)+1` , so even the first element is actually just beyond the size of D .

You can insert `cat(row)` in code and see.

I guess you will have to think about what `start` should be.